# Metal glue that cures in coldish weather?

Tags: adhesive, metal, storm-door

We have Pella glass storm doors that have been nothing but trouble since we bought them several years ago.

The handles connect to each other (through the metal door frame) via a bolt thats in the shape of a rectangular prism (that is, both interior and exterior handles have square receptacles that the rectangular bolt fits into). The handles then have hex screws that clamp down on the bolt via allen wrench:

[image]

[image]

The problem is, the hex screws loosen up habitually, and either loosen so much that the handles (when you go to use them) pull right off of the rectangular/squarish bolt (hence, you pull the handle right off the door) or even loosen so bad that they fall off. I've had to replace them several times, and being specialty parts, take weeks to come in.

Proper solution: tear the doors off and replace the Pellas with something better.

Quick n dirty solution: I'd like to glue the handles right on to the rectangular bolt.

**Is there a metal-to-metal glue that holds up reasonably well and that cures in 50 - 60 degree weather?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just about any 2 part epoxy would meet your requirements. However, gluing both sides is asking for trouble in the future.

Couple of ways around this. You could use loctite blue (thanks @jwh20 for steering us away from red) on the grub screws, which would be reversible but more secure than your current setup. You could lightly dimple the axle with a drill bit so that the grub screw is more secure. Or both. (If it was me, I'd just use the loctite.)

Comment: Do you really mean to suggest RED thread locker?  That's the "permanent" variety and if this ever needs to be service it will be difficult to get it apart.  BLUE thread locker is a better choice in my opinion.

Comment: I sit corrected. Thanks.